# GPO policies not applying across domain. Some workstations some not

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, group-policy, domain-controller

I've been trying to figure this one out for awhile now. I inherited a 200 user network running Win2k12 R2 DC. I noticed some domain firewalls are off on workstations and some are on. When sitting in front of the workstation, I noticed that I could enable and disable the firewall and on others it mentions that its controlled by GPO. I try and force gpo update and nothing seems to work.

After searching around I came across this.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3163622/ms16-072-security-update-for-group-policy-june-14-2016

KB3159398 seems to break GPO? Do you think this might be the culprit? The update is installed.

Comment: What you should do as a first step is to run gpresult on a working computer and on a non-working computer and compare them to see which GPO's are being applied and which are not.

Comment: Check the GPOs for WMI filters, Security filters and the Delegation tab. Provide screenshots if possible.